# TypeError: items is undefined while using DRF Api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to connect my React Frontend to my Django Backend using the Dango-REST-Framwork to create an API. But i can't fetch my data with React. After my tries didn't worked i tried [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) example in the React Documentation. Everytime i try to map and 'print' my result this error is shown:

> TypeError: items is undefined

#### Here is my code:

```py
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {ThemeNavbar} from '../../../components';
import EinsatzTableRow from './components/EinsatzTableRow';

import './EinsaetzePage.scss';


export default class EinsatzePage extends Component {
    state = {
        error: null,
        isLoaded: false,
        items: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/einsatzverwaltung/")
        .then(
          (result) => {
            this.setState({
              isLoaded: true,
              items: result.items
            });
          },
          // Note: it's important to handle errors here
          // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
          // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
          error => {
            this.setState({
              isLoaded: true,
              error
            });
          }
          );
        }

    render() {
        const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
        if (error) {
            return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
          } else if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div> <ThemeNavbar></ThemeNavbar><div>Loading...</div></div>;
          } else{
        return (
            <div className="">
               <ThemeNavbar></ThemeNavbar>
                <div className="container">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        {items.map(item => (
                            <EinsatzTableRow einsatznummer="" alarmierungszeit="" stichwort="" meldebild="" ort="" einsatzbericht_link="#"></EinsatzTableRow>
                        ))}
                        
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    }
  }
```

If i check the api page (http://localhost:8000/api/einsatzverwaltung/) everthing works:

```json
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "created": "2021-06-06T08:40:17.636978Z",
        "updated": "2021-06-06T08:40:17.636978Z",
        "status": 1,
        "einsatz_start": "2021-01-21T21:33:00Z",
        "einsatz_end": "2021-01-21T21:33:00Z",
        "einsatzort": "Test",
        "einsatzbericht": "ksnf jneog nroi nwoenf iownef inweof weio nwioe nfiowen ionweio cniweo cinwe iocwion c",
        "images": null,
        "meldebild": "Alarmo",
        "author": null,
        "stichwort": null,
        "alarmierungsart": null,
        "organisation": null,
        "fahrzeuge_ext": null
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "created": "2021-06-06T08:40:11.084004Z",
        "updated": "2021-06-06T08:40:11.084004Z",
        "status": 1,
        "einsatz_start": "2021-01-21T21:33:00Z",
        "einsatz_end": "2021-01-21T21:33:00Z",
        "einsatzort": "Test",
        "einsatzbericht": "ksnf jneog nroi nwoenf iownef inweof weio nwioe nfiowen ionweio cniweo cinwe iocwion c",
        "images": null,
        "meldebild": "Alarmo",
        "author": null,
        "stichwort": null,
        "alarmierungsart": null,
        "organisation": null,
        "fahrzeuge_ext": null
    }
]
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with react, but I assume the data doesn't return on result.items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using axios, and axios has a predefined schema for HTTP responses, you can take a look at here-
https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema

For your case, you need to correct the callback inside your `.then()` of the axios API call, something like this -

```js
axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/einsatzverwaltung/")
    .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: response.data
        });
    }
    // Note: it's important to handle errors here
    // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
    // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
    .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          error
        });
    })
);
```

I hope this would help, Always use `.catch()` for error handling.